# using R programming in java

Tags: java, r, statistics

We are working on a complex statistical project on `Java`. We did the original code in the [R programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29). Is there a way to convert this code to `Java` code (converter) or otherwise how can we use `R` in a `Java` project?

Answer (score 24):

While I'm unaware of a 'converter', there is an interface called rJava which will allow you to run R code directly from Java.

http://www.rforge.net/rJava/

> rJava is a simple R-to-Java interface.
> It is comparable to the .C/.Call C
> interface. rJava provides a low-level
> bridge between R and Java (via JNI).
> It allows to create objects, call
> methods and access fields of Java
> objects from R.
>
> In a sense the inverse of rJava is JRI
> (Java/R Interface) which provides the
> opposite direction - calling R from
> Java. JRI is now shipped as a part of
> the rJava package, although it still
> can be used as a separate entity
> (especially for development).
> Currently rJava is used as a part of
> JGR, iPlots and JavaGD
> software/packages.

Answer (score 11):

You can try Renjin (http://www.renjin.org):

"Renjin is a JVM-based interpreter for the R language for statistical computing. This project is an initiative of BeDataDriven, a company providing consulting in analytics and decision support systems."

Answer (score 2):

As @Seidr said, using rJava we can run R code directly from Java methods.

1. Open R console and install rJava package

   ```
   install.packages("rJava")
   ```

   Now you will find rJava in "**R home\library**"
2. Now in eclipse, add `JRI.jar`, `JRIEngine.jar`, `REngine.jar` to project build path. These jars are available in "**R home\library\rJava\jri**"
3. Create Rengine object.
4. Now create two vectors, add them and store in another variable. Now print that result variable in console.

   ```
   Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[]{"--no-save"},false,null);
   String aVector = "c(1,2,3)";
   String bVector = "c(4,5,6)";
   engine.eval("a<-"+aVector);
   engine.eval("b<-"+bVector);
   engine.eval("c<-a+b");

   System.out.println("Sum of two vectors : c = "+engine.eval("c"));
   ```

Hope below link helps (step-by-step procedure to integrate R in Java).

http://www.codophile.com/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rjava/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be advised that repeating answers given earlier and "link only" answers are generally frowned upon. Instead of just giving the link, summarize the steps in your answer and refer with the link to the original source. That way the answer doesn't become invalid when the link disappears. Also: that tutorial is incomplete (as explained further in the comments on that blog).

Answer (score 1):

The another option to run R on JVM is [FastR](https://github.com/oracle/fastr). According FastR's documentation:

> FastR is an implementation of the R Language in Java atop Truffle, a
>   framework for building self-optimizing AST interpreters.
>
> FastR is currently available in two forms:
>
> - As a pre-built binary with the Truffle implementations of Ruby and JavaScript for Linux and Mac OS X. Unfortunately, there is no Windows
>     version available yet.
> - As a source release on GitHub. This option does not come with Ruby or JavaScript.

Comment: More info here: https://medium.com/graalvm/faster-r-with-fastr-4b8db0e0dceb