# Integrate R in java web application

Tags: java, r, scala

I know there are multiple questions resembling this one but most of them are >2 years old and actually not that related.

What I need to do is fully integrate the R environment in an existing java (actually scala) application. I don't want any R-based web solutions like Rook, Rapache and the like, the server logic happens strictly in java land. What I need is a way to send R commands to the interpreter, let it run them and handle the output. More importantly, I need to be able to:

1. Run commands interactively not only ready-made R scripts.
2. Produce and handle graphics from the established graphics packages.
3. Communicate raw data back and forth between the JVM and R interpreter.

   I am aware of [JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/). I would very much appreciate to hear from anyone who has used it. How stable is it? How actively maintained is the project? Any existing code that I can look at? Any other alternatives out there?

Comment: Even though your question goes beyond the "how to integrate R in Java", it helps to link some related questions [\[1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451716/java-r-integration) [\[2\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034936/using-r-programming-in-java) [\[3\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180235/r-from-within-java).

Comment: Well, it is actually 3 questions. I would be interested to hear if/how anyone can deal with point 2 above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To locally call R from Java, you need JRI. To remotely call Java you can use RServe. If you want to handle graphics, that is best done using something in R such as the evaluate package. Afaik most language bridges offer no particular functionality for handling graphics, you will need to do that on the R level.

Have a look at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4806.pdf) before you get started to be aware of the challenges and limitations of using cross language bridges for scientific computing. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble down the line.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I won't mark the question as answered yet to see if some similarly useful and up-to-date answers can be collected here for reference. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider FastR, a GraalVM based implementation of R. This is a screenshot from Swing application showing a *lattice* plot from R.

[image]

FastR can be embedded like so:

```
Context ctx = Context.newBuilder("R").allowAllAccess(true).build();
ctx.eval("R", "sum").execute(new int[] {1,2,3});
```

You can instruct the R script to plot into given `Graphics2D` object:

```
ctx.eval("R", "function(g) awt(g, 400, 400)").execute(myGraphics2DObject)
ctx.eval("R", "grid.points(1:10)")
```

The full example is on GitHub: https://github.com/graalvm/examples/tree/master/fastr_javaui

More info about FastR: https://medium.com/graalvm/faster-r-with-fastr-4b8db0e0dceb